# Calculating daily averages in pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a Dataframe series with `30s` frequency.

```
df.head()
```

[image]

I want to calculate the daily averages for all signals in that series but it doesnt seem to work. I tried both

```
df_average = df.to_period('D')
df.resample('D')
```

And i get:
[image]

I want to have only 1 line per day. Why do i get more?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is DatetimeIndex only add an aggregate function, here `mean`, to `resample`:

```
df1 = df.resample('D').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael is sure way to go. Could also try;

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
```